# Any subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying property C is compact.

Tags: sequences-and-series, compactness

Define a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to have property C if every sequence with exactly one accumulation point in $X$ converges in $X$. (Recall that $x$ is an accumulation point of a sequence $(x_n)$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many $x_n$.)

Show that any subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying property C is compact.

Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Euclidean, compactness $\iff$ closed and bounded.
To show $X$ is closed, we can take any limit point $x$ of $X$. By definition of a limit point, we can find a sequence in $X$ converging to $x$. Then $x$ is the unique accumulation point of the sequence and hence by hypothesis $x\in X$

How can I show that $X$ is bounded?

Alternatively, I could show that $X$ is sequentially compact, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Your "proof" of closedness is flawed because the accumulation point might not be in $X$ so that you cannot use that $X$ has the property $C$.

Comment: Boundedness: If $X$ was unbounded, there would exist a sequence $(x_n)\subset X$ with $\|x_n\|\uparrow\infty$. Now, set $x_{2n}' = x_1$ and $x_{2n+1}' = x_n$. Then $(x_n')$ has exactly one accumulation point in $X$ but doesn't converge.

Comment: If a sequence has exactly one accumulation point, then it either converges to that point or a subsequence tends to $\infty$. Hence, every compact set has the property $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that $C$ is closed and bounded.

If it is unbounded, then let $\{x_n\}\subset C$ be an unbounded sequence, such that $\|x_n\|>n$.
 Set $$\cases{y_{2n}=x_1\\y_{2n+1}=x_n}$$
Then because of the requirement $\|x_n\|>n$, $x_1$ is the only accumulation point of $y$, which still doesn't converge.

If $C$ is not closed, then let $\{x_n\}\subset C$ be a sequence with limit $x\not\in C$. Then, again,  set $y$ as before. $x_1$ is the only accumulation point of $y$, yet $y$ doesn't converge.